# Swift: Overlay rectangle with text over view

Tags: ios, swift, shapes

If our app has a network connectivity error we would like to overlay a colored and transparent rectangle over the top of the screen with some "Network not available" like text.  The rectangle should cover the full width of the screen and the height should be enough to just show the text.   We would use a timer to only show the rectangle for a brief period of time.  How can you do this?

The actual view may be a UITableViewController, a UIViewController, or something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(2)

let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!

let rectangleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 20))
rectangleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 20))
label.text = "Network not available"

rectangleView.addSubview(label)

window.addSubview(rectangleView)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
    rectangleView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done overlays is to drag a new `UIViewController` into a storyboard, and drag a `UIView` into that. While laying out the UI it can be helpful to make the background color of the `UIViewController` black. When you're done laying out your elements inside the `UIView`, change the background color of the `UIViewController` to transparent.

Here's an example of a profile overlay:

[image: screenshot of an overlay view controller in a storyboard]

In this case I've actually made the `UIViewController` background a gray color with an alpha of about 50%. Then when I present this view controller using a fade transition it looks like it appears over top the current context:

```
func showOverlay() {
    //
    guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myOverlay") as? UIViewController else {
        print("failed to get myOverlay from MyStoryboard")
        return
    }

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
        // after 3 seconds, dismiss the overlay
        dispatchAfterSeconds(3) {
            vc.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    })
}
```

This uses a handy function, `dispatchAfterSeconds`:

```
// execute function after delay using GCD
func dispatchAfterSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    let triggerTime = Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * seconds)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(triggerTime) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: { () -> Void in
        completion()
    })
}
```

Note that when I talk about changing the background color of the `UIViewController`, what I actually mean by that is the background color of the view created by default inside of a `UIViewController` that has been created in a storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But the solution I'm after would just show the bar (rectangle) with text at the top of the screen.  The actual screen would still be usable while the text is displayed.  Ie: the text would appear over a table and you could still scroll the table while the text is there.   Instagram uses a similar approach for their networking alert message.  It seems this approach shows the new view fully over the existing view which makes the existing view not usable while the alert is shown.